# C# SQL Query results to string list

Tags: c#, list, converters, sqldatareader

Hi I want to query my database and return all the results as a string
At the moment my code is like this

```
SqlDataReader DR = query.ExecuteReader();
  while (DR.Read())
{
    stringList.Add (DR.GetString(0));
}
```

With stringList being a list of strings, my question is how do I convert all results to a string. Thanks

Comment: Is stringList a type List<string> ?

Comment: What do you mean by "all results"?  All columns?

Comment: `SqlDataReader` has a [`GetValues`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getvalues(v=vs.110).aspx) method that will return an object array that you could easily join using `string.Join`

Comment: This is almost always a **really bad idea**. If you have non-string data in the query, you'll really help yourself by working with the appropriate data type.

Comment: I can't upvote Joel's comment enough, so I'll expand on it and state that taking any non-string value (DateTime, Int, etc) and converting it at the Data layer instantly, it makes any type of sorting, presentation etc of those value's now much more difficult.  Even if you are doing a simple CSV export file, convert the value at the very last moment (that way if someone comes back with a requirement to sort, it's extremely easy).

Comment: To add to this, you can always turn your concrete object into a string with a method or by overriding the `ToString()` and doing it there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to join a all the elements of a List to a single string, the way to do it is call the join method on the string class, as D Stanley has suggested.

Here is a simple example.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/96cY4y

```
public static void Main()
{
    List<string> stringList = new List<string>();
    stringList.Add("Hello");
    stringList.Add("world");
    var strOut = string.Join(" ",stringList.ToArray());
    Console.WriteLine(strOut);
}
```